# managing stage and production environments in Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, environment

I was just about to set up a 2nd GA property that I would implement into my Staging environment. I figured i'd do the same with GTM and just export/import containers from Stage to Production whenever necessary. I also figured I'd dynamically populate the Tracking-ID dynamically based on hostname. No big deal.

But then I stumbled across Environments for GTM. The first bit I read said that using this feature would solve the problem of moving code across environments. To me this implied that the snippet code would remain the same in all environments and that there would be no need to change (dynamically, via build script, manually or otherwise) any values or anything... that GTA was smart enough to deploy the right container(s) to the right place(s) at the right time(s). That sounds great, I'll do it.

Now that I'm getting into that process I'm learning (if I'm understanding correctly) that each environment does in face have to have a separate snippet. So now I"m back to where I started, with having to dynamically add values to the snippets based on domain name (which determines stage or test). With out that, every time the file containing the snippet is pushed between environments, it will contain the wrong values. I guess using Environments still takes out the export/import process for containers (which, don't get me wrong, is nice) but having to change those values is a pain..

**Is this the long and short of it - do I have this right? Is there any way around having to change code in the web page (or template) by doing it somehow through GTM instead?** I'm guessing not, since the snippet is the base of GTM's functionality, but i figure I'd ask.

Further complicating things is that I was planning to use a Wordpress plugin, Google Tag Manager for Wordpress, to add the GTM code. in this case, all I can even change is is the Tracking-ID, which actually stays the same... it's other values that change that I have no control over with the plugin. **Is anyone aware of a way to inject new values into the snippet that the plugin writes to the page?**

Answer (score 0):

The snippet for an environment has the same GTM id, but has a token for the environment name attached to the GTM url. If you use any kind of build system it should be possible to set or change the token according to the server you deploy to. Personally I am not convinced that environments are really useful.

If all you need is different values for tracking ids, you can implement lookup table variables that take hostname variable as input and return the respective tracking id for live or staging. Then use that instead of hardcoding the tracking id into your tag.

Comment: yeah that's what I did... just another thing to configure. I just wanted to make sure I was accurately understanding how environments worked - sounds like I am. Like I said, I see the use in being able to push containers between environments all from the same account (as opposed to exporting what's in Stage and importing into Production). any reasons why doing it the export/import way might be preferable?